# Start a su command in a Vagrant

Tags: shell-script, ssh, sudo, vagrant

I have a Vagrant machine, but I cannot change the vagrant configuration.

I want to access to the vagrant machine, switch to superuser and then launch some commands. How can I do this in one shot or in a script file?

By now I'm able to access to vagrant as su with this command:

`vagrant ssh -c "cd /opt/path && sudo su"`

But if I launch other commands like this:

`vagrant ssh -c "cd /opt/path && sudo su -c \"nvm use 10.16.0\""`

I have this log:

```
bash: nvm: command not found
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

A simple echo, instead, works fine. this command:

`vagrant ssh -c "cd /opt/path && sudo su -c \"echo \"hello\"\""`

logs:

```
hello
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

Comment: It looks like a basic $PATH issue: where is located the `nvm` binary ? Did you tried by specifying the full path to it ? (for example, if `nvm` is under /usr/local/bin, then call `/usr/local/bin/nvm`).

Comment: Is nvm installed for the `root` user or for the `vagrant`  user? The problem is that normally the nvm command is set from your .bashrc file

Comment: @binarym this is my `$PATH` output: `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0` I try using `/root/.nvm/nvm` but doesn't work

Comment: @user2563661 for the root user

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that the `nvm` command is set from the `root` user's `.bashrc` file. When you run `su user` the user's environment will not be used except for `HOME` and `SHELL` and additionally `USER` and `LOGNAME` for non-root users.

Normally, you would use the `--login` flag of `su` to use the user's environment (or just `-` for short). However, this is not enough when you want to source the `.bashrc` file since `.bashrc` will be sourced for interactive shells only.

I would suggest trying to move the nvm code from `/root/.bashrc` to `/root/.bash_profile` and run the command as `vagrant ssh -c "cd /opt/path && sudo su --login -c \"nvm use 10.16.0\""`. So whatever nvm added to `.bashrc`, e.g.:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

just move to `/root/.bash_profile`

Just as a side note, I don't think it is the best idea to install nvm for the `root` user. It would be much safer to install it for `vagrant`.

Comment: Thnak you, but for entrerprise policy I cannot change any internal vagrant configuration, so I need to workaround this limitation in another way

Comment: @ufollettu I think you could also run the lines of nvm code from `.bashrc` manually before running nvm, e.g., `sudo su -c "export NVM_DIR="/root/.nvm" ; ... ; nvm use 10"`